# Visual studio code - closes window after launching

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have problems with launching my VSC after windows update. The window closes just after lauching. I have installed new version of vsc 1.73.1 and I have deleted the directory with extensions but it haven't helped. I use win 10. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might have an extension that's misbehaving and causing this. Try running `code --disable-extensions` - this will launch VSCode with all extensions disabled. If it launches successfully, you might then try Extension Bisect to narrow down the faulty one.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Flag code --disable-extensions doesn't work but I have tried --no-sandbox and it is working.